# Meta key bindings

Tags: cloud9-ide

How to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Down</kbd> combination for Windows Chrome (default keystroke)?

Is it possible, without config overriding?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use this press <kbd>windows key</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>down arrow</kbd> at the same time.

Comment: Wow, it named "Cmd" instead of "Meta" in Win. Thanks!